# Express server errors with external IP, works fine otherwise

Tags: node.js, express

I have an Express server - very small at the moment, this is my whole code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hey!')
})

app.listen(port, 'my.ip.address')
```

It works just fine when `my.ip.address` is localhost/0.0.0.0/127.0.0.1/192.168.0.28 (my network IP.) But when my external IP is provided, I get this:

```
events.js:298
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available myip:8080
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1292:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1357:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1496:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1336:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  errno: -99,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: myip,
  port: 8080
}
```

I know that 8080 is correctly forwarded, as another example server (Apache) works just fine, and can be connected to from my external IP.

Comment: Have you tried a different port? Two applications can't use the same port... e.g. apache and node can't both listen on 8080.

Comment: @CodyＧ Yes. I get the same error.

Comment: is "myip" bound to any network interface on your computer? or are you assuming that your "external ip" is the same? Your external ip could be your router's IP. which means you can't assign to it... (e.g. does it show up in `ifconfig`?)

Comment: myip being my external ip, it shouldn't be bound to anything. External IP is my WAN/Internet IP. It doesn't show in ifconfig,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TLDR:

Just listen to the port and remove the IP address:

```
app.listen(port)
```

#### What's happening:

When you do the following:

```
app.listen(port, 'my.ip.address')
```

What you are doing is telling your OS that you want to listen to incoming packet from the port on the network card that owns that IP address.

If the OS cannot find any network card (ethernet, wifi etc.) that has that IP address assigned then your OS will error out saying it cannot find the hardware you want to listen to.

Since your external IP is owned by the external network device of your router your OS cannot find the hardware that owns the IP address.

#### Altenate solution

You can just listen to the IP address assigned to the network card that is connected to your router:

```
    app.listen(port, 'my.local.ip.address')
```

Comment: What @slebetman said plus you should never define your port like that. You should be using `process.env.PORT` for all ports with two pipes for a suggested port when for some reason there isn't one defined. Ex. `const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080